# Sync SQLite with SQL Server 2012 Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-sync-framework

I am working with one Windows 8 app using SQLite database. now i wanted to sync SQLite with SQL Server 2012, there are lots of things available  but not proper for Windows 8 app. Can any one help me out

Thanks

Comment: are u able to sync the DB ..i am also do the same please provide any reference..

Comment: no i am not able to sync

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this link. 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5719/sync-sqlite-with-sql-server-merge-replication

It should work for Windows 8 as the SQLite is cross platform. There is a Sqlite implementation for Windows 8 App. http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Comment: I tried lots of blogs all blogs just not having complete info